# App fails to be built when Titanium Appcelerator Module with EventKit is integrated

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules, ekeventkit

I am working on titanium app with Calendar module I created before almost 6 months ago. When I had created the module for Calendar, I was using Snow Leopard. But recently I have upgraded my machine for Lion and now, when I tried to modify the module, It game me path error, which I solved with '~'. And module also built successfully. But when I integrate it with the app, app was being crashed and even can't be built. This is very weird, because till date the module was working but now when I tried to build the app with latest module, it's not working.

When I write `EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];` it crashes. When I comment this, the app builds perfect. I don't know why this happens. The module is built successfully but when integrated with app then the app fails to be built.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone have answer about this and worked with EventKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In module.xcconfig, try to put

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework EventKit
```

Because when you run the application, the framework which is being used by the module should be put in this file in `OTHER_LDFLAGS`